# Prepare For Segue Swift

Tags: swift, segue

I am creating a map app and I have created a segue from the "info" button to below UI;

[image]

However now I am unsure how to setup the **prepare for segue** as I want:

1. The image to be imported which is **not** featured on the first view
2. The Title to be imported which is on the first view
3. The Description to be imported which is **not** on the first view

I was going to use this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
}
```

but I am unsure how to make it unique for all 20 pins. Is this possible? Or do I need the image & description on the first view.
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the image and description?

Comment: I have the image stored in the Xcode project files as **wind_wand.jpeg** and the description as **wind_wand_desc.txt**